# Why are "Step Into (F5)" and "Step Over (F6)" disabled after breakpoint is hit in Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging my Android app using Eclipse. The app runs in Android Emulator, not on a real phone. After a breakpoint is hit, only `Resume (F8)` and `Run to Line (Ctrl+R)` are enabled, while `Step Into (F5)` and `Step Over (F6)` are disabled:

[image]

The breakpoint is set to "Suspend VM", if that has any relevance:

[image]

Why are they disabled, and is there any way to enabled them?

**Edit:** I tried placing a second breakpoint on the next line, then hit Resume, and when that second breakpoint was hit, "Step Into (F5)" and "Step Over (F6)" were no longer disabled. I don't know if this will work every time though.

Answer (score 3):

In order for the control button to activate you just need to choose the thread that your code is running on from the Debug window.

In Debug perspective, choose the thread that is marked Suspended from the Debug window.

Answer (score 0):

Usually step into works for a method or a constructor initalization or aything like that. We can also step into inbuilt methods in Android Studio now as the class gets decompiled. maybe that particular line was an assignment statement or something that cannot be stepped into.

Comment: I'm on Eclipse, not Android Studio. Sorry for any misunderstanding.